Can I ask and self-answer a question where there's an ongoing investigation into possible/better solutions (by myself and others)?
I like the policy of self-answered questions, as it's a good way to document things I discover for my own use with the additional benefit of possible commentary by others.
However, a recent issue I wanted to self-document/-answer is one that people have tried to solve in various ways over at least 10 years, is very thorny/complex/obscure[d], and there are a host of workable/partial/imperfect solutions that attack it at various layers of the issue. Additionally, there are lots of people trying to solve it properly/cleanly and some have long documented blogs on their progress (which I would obviously have to summarize/cull greatly to pull into my question or answer section). Simply put, there are no truly clean answers and I'm looking to both help others and get more help towards it.
I even have a device mfg who wants a good summary of the issue and current methods as they may potentially modify their line of devices to add one of these solutions as a feature, but I don't want that info stuck in an email thread where it may potentially stay and be useless in pursuit of the larger goal, whether this mfg acts or not.
My desire is to collect the enormous amount of information (largely outside SE) and links I've found on it in a question that will hopefully serve as both a springboard for others trying to solve it (as I do have some solutions inc. ones not (or not well) documented on Stack Exchange, so this isn't purely a discovery mission) plus either contribute to better solutions with feedback or comment on the feasibility of the solutions I haven't tried yet (some are costly).
My other concern is if there's an automatic timeout for questions as I can only find the 5-close-vote mechanism but nothing about a time limit before whatever I've written is just frozen whether it has reached a good state or not.
EDIT: To address some feedback that this (understandably) sounds like some personal blog/quest/journey/project, here is a brief explanation to explain the scope of it: It is a technical issue affecting anyone using more than one monitor and HDMI/Displayport who is tired of having the monitors disconnect and destroy their window layout (a lot of people). It is a problem with a precise description and cause(s), so easily able to be asked, outlined and have its angles considered. But despite what a 5-minute google search (or search here) may suggest, it's an incredibly difficult problem to solve cleanly and completely depending on your situation.
Again, please don't try to answer it here as I'm literally only bringing it up to show it's not some minor personal vanity project that will stuff SE with more chaff and BS. I'm planning to make a serious effort to at least consolidate all of the information I have on it and the existing and potential solutions for it. I just don't want to invest the time doing it on SE if 1) it will be closed/frozen prematurely, 2) it will be flagged for some reason.
Thank you for any help.

An answer can't be a collection of links. In fact it shouldn't be necessary to click on any links to make sense of the answer. It sounds like you're proposing writing something that's not really an answer. You might like to see on the appropriate site-meta whether what you're suggesting would be well received.

On first glance/read, looks like SE isn't the place for this, sadly. It's Q&A site, not meant for personal blogs/documentation. I'll have to dig deeper though, if others won't give decent answers before that.

@RobertLongson: It's not just a collection of links. That's really ancillary so people could fork from this thread to the longer versions.
I was going to summarize/cull/copy the relevant parts so they were in the question (or answer) and just link to the original since there was more detail elsewhere.

@ShadowWizard: This isn't a personal blog. I didn't want to delve into any details since this isn't the place, but I may have done my question a major disservice by not doing so. I'm going to edit the original to explain since you've brought up this chink in the armor.

if you copy anything you'd need to provide attribution and ensure the amount that you copy is limited to fair-use to avoid copyright infringement/plagiarism.

@RobertLongson I just mean copy in the sense of bringing some meaningful summary or explanation of the linked information into the question so it is whole and stands on its own. This is per requests I've seen everywhere on SE to do that so, just as you said, it doesn't become a collection of links, especially dead ones.

There's no time limit/statute of limitations (so to speak) on how long you can edit/add answers.
I think the difficulty is in balancing collating what you've tried so far, vs keeping a Q/A pair that is reasonably scoped and trivially usable.
I'd say this is an example of how I'd done it in the past - I kept most of my research as brief as possible, and separated my answer into sections. I touched as briefly as possible on the things that didn't work for me. While there's temptation to go into depth, I think its enough to know what you tried and why it didn't work in the most minimalist terms.
I'd hold off on self answering till I'd had a somewhat definitive answer, and focus on one approach per answer - I've documented 2 approaches here, basically cause one works universally, and the other later let me work out the why

Thanks man, that's a great answer. Oddly enough, your answer is how I set up one of my other questions from the past so I think we're really on the same page. My main concern was extending that format [too much] and wasting ton of time on something that would be removed/flagged/deleted. But per your suggestion I do have several partial-to-workable fixes so far, so I think I'll just trudge on ahead with that and work the rest out.
